# Rotating character and camera in FPS

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im trying to make the camera movement in Unity but I have a problem, the player will always start with a rotation 0,0,0, even I rotate it in Y before playing.

I the code I rotate the player in Y axis and the camera in X, so the player wont rotate when looking up-down.

Here is the code:

```
public float cameraSpeed;
//public float smooth = 2;
[Range(0f, 1f)] public float smooth = 0.5f;
Vector2 mouseLook;
Vector2 smoothV;

private Transform cameraTransform;


void Start()
{
    //Inicializamos componentes
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    cameraTransform = Camera.main.transform;

    mouseLook.y = Mathf.Clamp(-cameraTransform.localRotation.x, -75, 50);
    mouseLook.x = transform.localRotation.y;
}

void CameraMovement()
{
    //Declaramos un vector con la direccion del raton
    Vector2 md = new Vector2(InputManager.main.HorizontalMouse(), InputManager.main.VerticalMouse());
    md *= cameraSpeed / smooth;
    smoothV = Vector2.Lerp(smoothV, md, smooth);
    mouseLook += smoothV;

    //Limitamos el angulo de la camara para que no de vueltas
    mouseLook = new Vector2(mouseLook.x, Mathf.Clamp(mouseLook.y, -75, 50));

    //Hacemos que rote la camara en el eje x y el jugador en el eje y
    Camera.main.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(-mouseLook.y, Vector3.right);
    transform.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(mouseLook.x  , transform.up);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of you haven't keeping rotation value continuously. you started always using mouse rotation that is why so just keep rotation value like

```
Camera.main.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(-mouseLook.y, Vector3.right) * Camera.main.transform.localRotation;
transform.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(mouseLook.x  , transform.up) * transform.localRotation;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `mouseLook` is always `0, 0` in the first frame. So when you do

```
mouseLook += smoothV;
```

The first time you have always a value starting from a `zero` vector.

---

You should store the initial rotation (and btw also the mainCamera to avoid always getting it via `Camera.main`) like e.g.

```
private Transform cameraTransform;

private void Start()
{
    cameraTransform = Camera.main.transform;

    mouseLook.y = MathfClamp(-cameraTransform.localRotation.x, -75, 50);
    mouseLook.x = transform.localRotation.y;
}
```

---

Then in your `smooth` calculation since both components `x` and `y` are equal for

```
md = Vector2.Scale(md, new Vector2(cameraSpeed * smooth, cameraSpeed * smooth));
```

you could also use a simple `float` multiplication like

```
md *= cameraSpeed * smooth;
```

Then instead of `Lerp` the `x` and `y` component individually you can use

```
smoothV = Vector2.Lerp(smoothV, md, 1f / smooth);
```

I would actually recommend for better understanding to rather use

```
[Range(0f, 1f)] public float smoothFactor = 0.5f;
```

and then accordingly

```
md *= cameraSpeed / smoothFactor;
smoothV = Vector2.Lerp(smoothV, md, smoothFactor);
```

Comment: Hi, thx for the answer. I have edited everything but it will start looking to 0,0,0 again, I have updated my question with the new code